# Ubuntu 21.10 directory and files icons missing when opening file manager from applications (ctrl + O)

Tags: icons, 21.10, filemanager

I recently updated to Ubuntu 21.10, but now directory and files icons are missing when trying to open files from any applications (typically using ctrl + O). Here are two examples from mozilla firefox and the atom editor:

Mozilla firefox:
[image: This is from Mozilla firefox]

Atom editor:
[image: This is from the Atom editor]

Note that the problem looks slightly different between the two cases, though the source is probably common ..

Any hint ?

Comment: Perhaps clearing your cache may help out: `rm ~/.cache`. Then log out and back in. Any cache data of all apps will be erased, but will be recreated as needed.

Comment: It worked for most app ! (some of them were saving cache elsewhere as well it seems)